# How to translate this small part of TensorFlow code into pyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

How to translate this small part of TensorFlow code into pyTorch?

```
def transforms(x):
        # stft returns spectogram for each sample and each eeg
        # input X contains 3 signals, apply stft for each 
        # and get array with shape [samples, num_of_eeg, time_stamps, freq]
        # change dims and return [samples, time_stamps, freq, num_of_eeg]
        spectrograms = tf.signal.stft(x, frame_length=32, frame_step=4, fft_length=64)
        spectrograms = tf.abs(spectrograms)
        return tf.einsum("...ijk->...jki", spectrograms)
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for similar functions in PyTorch, which would do the same thing as those functions in Tensorflow? Which line were you unable to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the doc for STFT pytorch implementation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stft.html). The rest is fast-forward. It should be:

```py
def transforms(x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """Return Fourrier spectrogram."""
    spectrograms = torch.stft(x, win_length=32, n_fft=4, hop_length=64)
    spectrograms = torch.abs(spectrograms)
    return torch.einsum("...ijk->...jki", spectrograms)
```

Comment: Did you actually try? I tried this, comparing the outputs, and it is not the same. The shape is already different for `spectograms`. I currently struggle to get the same output of `stft`.

Comment: What is your version of torch?

Comment: 1.13.1 but I'm sure it does not matter. Did you actually try? See also this: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/100177